# Use spring-data-rest without jpa but only JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, jdbctemplate, spring-data-jdbc

Is it possible to use [spring-data-rest](/questions/tagged/spring-data-rest) without [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa)?

In my application I use `JdbcTemplate`. Can this be wired to spring-data-rest somehow?

**Update from 4 years later:**

Meanwhile there is [spring-data-jdbc](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jdbc) which looks like it answers the original question.

See: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can't. From the [introduction section of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#intro-chapter):

> Spring Data REST builds on top of Spring Data repositories and automatically exports those as REST resources

If you're using `JdbcTemplate` for you data access, rather than using Spring Data repositories (be it JPA or any of the other supported back ends) then there is nothing for Spring Data REST to build on and export as REST resources.

Comment: But in case you implement the Repository interface using the jdbcTemplate, it should be possible, right? I'd like to it, but no success so far ...